# Openrefine memory pb

Tags: dataset, openrefine

Hello everyone and thanks for help,

First, I'm a begginner in database uses and It. Please be indulgent with me. Moreover I'm a ubuntu user on Xfce environment.

I'm trying to use Openrefine with a dataset of approximately 11 000 rows and 8 colums. When I try to treat it, I encounter a memory pb. " Memory usage: 100% (1517/1517MB)"

like this :

[capture of memory pb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnxhz.png)

I've tried to allocate more memory to openrefine by writing the command :
./ refine -m 1800m

I've read that I can't allocated more than the half of my free memory that is 3800 m. But even with more memory i've waited a night long and openrefine doesn't treat the dataset. I don't understand why, because openrefine is supposed to can treat about 100 000 raws with a few colums.

I was using firefox browser. I tried Opera that is considered by openrefine more convenient for openrefine, but I have the same result.

Some people more used to dataset treatment could help me ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling cell parsing on import?

You may also try to use CSV instead of ods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried in CSV and it works !  When I changed the format from ods to CSV earlier I thought that it was not a good idea because the file was heavier. In any case, my problem is solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To give an "official" answer to your question: [ODS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) sometimes it is quite a burdon on the parser.
Therefore you can get around some limitations by exporting/importing your data as CSV, which is easier to read.

As described in the [OpenRefine documentation about increasing memory allocation](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/installing#increasing-memory-allocation) you may also benefit from turning the automatic cell type parsing off.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. I'll know how to deal with that kind of problem next time.